# `it` is a typo or something else?

Tags: pronouns

The latest Trump's twitter

> Based on the Tariffs and Trade Barriers long placed on the U.S. and it 
>   great companies and workers by the European Union, if these Tariffs and Barriers are not soon broken down and removed, we will be placing a 20% Tariff on all of their cars coming into the U.S. Build them here!

[image: Image of Tweet, text quoted above]

What does  it here  mean?

> Based on the Tariffs and Trade Barriers long placed on the U.S. and it great companies and workers by the European Union,

Maybe it is a typo?

The right sentence maybe:

> Based on the Tariffs and Trade Barriers long placed on the U.S. and great companies and workers by the European Union,

Comment: Typo for **its**, the possessive, the US's. Do not use those tweets as examples of clear, cogent English. The tariffs have been placed on the US and its great companies and workers.

Comment: 1. Twitter is no place to expect standard English grammar, spelling or other conventions. 2. Donald Trump's Twitter feed is no place to expect standard English grammar, spelling, or other conventions even by the standards of Twitter. 3. Donald Trump's Twitter feed is no place to expect standard English grammar, spelling, or other conventions even by the standards of Donald Trump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo for its, the possessive, the US's. Do not use those tweets as examples of clear, cogent English. The tariffs have been placed on the US and its great companies and workers